# Como gravar imagem no banco de dados com JSF2

Tags: hibernate, upload, jsf-2.2, file-upload

Estou com um projeto `JSF` com o modelo *DAO* usando `Hibernate`, e estou tendo muita dificuldade para entender como salvar a imagem no banco de dados.

Eu somente precisaria saber como ficaria o método para salvar uma imagem em uma classe *DAO* e como ele ficaria na classe `Bean`.

Encontrei esse vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2b3KQApdOAU

Para mim esse vídeo não serve pois ele salva em disco. Eu fiz essas postagem no site de GUJ mas não obtive resultado: http://www.guj.com.br/39728-como-gravar-imagens-na-base-de-dados-em-jsf

Esse chegou mais próximo do que precisava: http://www.guj.com.br/39230-jsf2---upload-de-imagens

Esse foi um repositório que encontrei: https://github.com/wladyband/fileupload

Esse é o projeto pelo qual estou trabalhando: https://github.com/wladyband/Drogaria/tree/master/Drogaria

E essa é a classe que quero introduzir a modificação: https://github.com/wladyband/Drogaria/blob/master/Drogaria/src/br/com/drogaria/domain/Produto.java

Comment: E, especificamente, qual a sua dúvida? Você disse que verificou alguns projetos, você testou a solução usada neles? Se sim, teve algum problema?

Answer (score 1):

Já que voce não postou o código, veja se isso pode te ajudar:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "fileUploadMB")
@RequestScoped
public class fileUploadMB {
    public static byte[] arquivo;
    public static String nomeArquivo;
    private Ouvidoria ouvidoriaCadastro;



    public Ouvidoria getOuvidoriaCadastro() {
        if (ouvidoriaCadastro == null) {
            ouvidoriaCadastro = new Ouvidoria();
        }
        return ouvidoriaCadastro;
    }


    public void setOuvidoriaCadastro(Ouvidoria ouvidoriaCadastro) {
        this.ouvidoriaCadastro = ouvidoriaCadastro;
    }

    /* Método que faz o Upload dos arquivos */
    public void doUpload(FileUploadEvent fileUploadEvent) throws IOException {

        UploadedFile uploadedFile = fileUploadEvent.getFile();

        String fileNameUploaded = uploadedFile.getFileName();
        long fileSizeUploaded = uploadedFile.getSize();
        System.out.println(uploadedFile);

        // arquivo = uploadedFile.getContents();
        String infoAboutFile = "<br/> Arquivo recebido: <b>" + fileNameUploaded
                + "</b><br/>" + "Tamanho do Arquivo: <b>" + fileSizeUploaded
                + "</b>";
        //Mensagem exibida na tela
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        facesContext.addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage("Sucesso", infoAboutFile));

        arquivo = (IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedFile.getInputstream()));
        nomeArquivo = uploadedFile.getFileName();

        ouvidoriaCadastro.setArquivo(arquivo);
        ouvidoriaCadastro.setNomeArquivo(fileNameUploaded);
        ouvidoriaCadastro.setNomeArquivo(nomeArquivo);

        System.out.println("Arquivo capturado" + arquivo);
        System.out.println("Nome do Arquivo" + nomeArquivo);

    }



}
```

Na sua pagina xml:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Selecione um Arquivo(Opcional):" />
            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadMB.doUpload}"
                mode="advanced" showButtons="false" label="Enviar Arquvios.."
                auto="true" />
```